# Particle System Hair Rotation not working

Tags: particles, hair, blenderkit

I want to apply hair to a curved face and have the hair all pointing straight up.
I get no change when changing rotation settings in Particle System - Hair - Advanced - Rotation.
Is there something else that needs to be done?